# What's the best practice to store events with NodeJs and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to store all the database interactions(CRUD) in a collection, I research about but I didn't find a best way to do this.

My app works with mongoose and I can use the pre/post hooks for insert this information in a collection. [Mongoose Midleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Are there are others options for implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)So technically if you're asking for catching the CRUD operations performed on mongodb ,Mongoose is an ORM(Object Relational Mapper) which does the job for you, but just in the conventional sort of Relational DB's like MSSQL Server ,the only hooks available to track the firing queries or DB transactions were triggers.Similarly,you can use triggers and listeners in mongodb ,check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-triggers

2) You can use something what mongo itself provides called as Tailable Cursors see the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/